# How to make a message pop up on message area screen on a app? like any text service

Tags: text, ios7, message

I have a text message area done and so far i have messages come on in on viewscreen but i have to refresh everytime to see these incoming messages where messages come in. I just want the incoming messages show up like a chat how do i do this. **i just want to messages to pop up like imessages.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use for push notifications. See [Apple's Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) for all the documentation on how to set up push notifications for your app.

Comment: I have push notification already working. But when I get a new message it doesn't show on message area. I have to refresh the page then messages show. I just want the messages to show on the screen without refreshing the page 

Thanks

Comment: Maybe add some code to your question, showing what you're currently doing, what's not working, what you've tried, etc.